# How does OR operator works in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query which make me to thought that how does `OR` operator in SQL works.

```
SELECT * FROM crop WHERE  `crop_id`=1 OR  ''='' ;
```

what i assumed that out put will be with records having `crop_id` equals to `1` because I have records with that value, and logically it does not evaluates the 2nd condition.

But it is returning all the records, rather than returning filtered(with crop_id) values.

Am I taking it wrong?

**Update**

I have a condition that if `crop_id`=1 matches it should return all the values having crop_id = 1 other wise return all records.

**Upadte 2**

Query mentioned above have **both** conditions **are true**, i.e `crop_id=1 and ''=''` I don't want alternatives, I just want to know that **why** it is **ignoring first condition** and taking 2nd condition.

Comment: `WHERE something OR TRUE` => **always TRUE**, It is called Boolean Logic

Comment: The same as `WHERE 1=1 OR rest_is_pointless`. It's a way to ignore your logic if you want to see all records. But pointless in your final query. I often use `WHERE 1=1 AND otherconditions`, then you can put every condition in it's own line to comment them out easily if desired.

Comment: @lad2025 see the update.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Question updated

Comment: `SET @param = 1; SELECT * FROM crop WHERE crop_id = @param OR @param IS NULL` If you don't provide @param (@param = NULL) you will get all data, if @param is provided you will get only data you need

Comment: Where is this sql, in a stored-procedure? Then i would use an `If ... Else` according to the parameter value, otherwise you can use `WHERE  @crop_id IS NULL OR crop_id = @crop_id`

Comment: @OAD You can use also **COALESCE** like: `SELECT * FROM crop WHERE crop_id = COALESCE(@crop_id, crop_id)`. If @crop_id is NULL then you will get crop_id = crop_id => always true => all rows

Comment: @OAD, your update #1 says, if crop=1 return then else return all crop != 1, which techincally means all record only, because either conditions are true or false, Please check your requirement you are seriously confuse on what you need.

Comment: @SumitGupta my requirement is clear I m sorry if i m not able to convey it. I am simply asking that my first condition is true, then it should return one record only, but it is not working like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your original question the answer is:**

```
WHERE something OR TRUE -- always TRUE
```

So you will get always all records.

**For second question it looks like you want**:

You pass in `@param` value specific value e.g. `1` or `NULL`;

```
SELECT * 
FROM crop 
WHERE crop_id = @param OR @param IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM crop 
WHERE crop_id = COALESCE(@param, crop_id);
```

You can also use `IF ELSE` for this like:

```
IF @param IS NULL THEN
   SELECT * 
   FROM crop
ELSE
   SELECT * 
   FROM crop 
   WHERE crop_id = @param 
END IF
```

**EDIT:**

> ## People says you don't need to know Math to be programmer.

This is exactly the case when Math(Boolean Logic) is needed.

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ Statement_1 ║ Statement_2 ║  AND  ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════╣
║ TRUE        ║ TRUE        ║ TRUE  ║
║ FALSE       ║ TRUE        ║ FALSE ║
║ TRUE        ║ FALSE       ║ FALSE ║
║ FALSE       ║ FALSE       ║ FALSE ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝

╔═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ Statement_1 ║ Statement_2 ║  OR   ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════╣
║ TRUE        ║ TRUE        ║ TRUE  ║
║ FALSE       ║ TRUE        ║ TRUE  ║
║ TRUE        ║ FALSE       ║ TRUE  ║
║ FALSE       ║ FALSE       ║ FALSE ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝
```

Now `Statement_2` is `'' = ''` which is always **TRUE**

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╦══════╗
║ Statement_1 ║ Statement_2 ║  OR  ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬══════╣
║ TRUE        ║ TRUE        ║ TRUE ║
║ FALSE       ║ TRUE        ║ TRUE ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩══════╝
```

As you see the result is always **`TRUE`**.  And there is no need to evaluate `Statement_1`.

```
condition OR TRUE <=> TRUE     (THIS IS TAUTOLOGY!!!)
```

> Tautology is a formula that is true in every possible interpretation

And finally your condition is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 1=1 -- will return all records
```

Comment: @OAD I can't explain it simpler

Comment: @OAD No problem, I understand your doubts, but when you play with logic/electronic and logic gates it will be very clear ;)

Answer (score 3):

`OR`

it works as in any `boolean` statement.

> what i assumed that out put will be with records having crop_id equals to 1 because I have records with that value, and logically it does not evaluates the 2nd condition.

You are right, but if you don't have value `equal to` 1 then it evaluates the second part and it returns `true` and hence you always get result, either you match or not to your first part of `OR`.

Comment: you are right but it is not true so, it is returning me the all values, even though have value with `crop_id=1`

Comment: @OAD because *one* of the conditions are `true`

Comment: not sure what you really mean by `not true`. `''=''` will always be true so any part on left of `OR` doesn't make difference in out come.

Answer (score 3):

The boolean logic of OR operator is as below:

```
true OR true = true
false OR true = true
true OR false = true
false OR false = false
```

So in your SQL query, you put `'' = ''` so your boolean logic evaluates to true for this, so you will get all results for this too. If you want to get results with `crop_id = 1` only, then use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM crop WHERE  `crop_id`=1
```

There is no need to use the `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

for your desired output or will not be used rather if else will be used. i.e.

you have to

```
 select count (*) from crop where 'crop_id'=1 
if count>0
{
select * from crop where 'crop_id'=1
}else
{
select * from crop;

}
```

because or works like it will give all the results of equal to 1 and all the empty ones as well.
as or means either of the condition should be true.
so either it is 1 then it will come.
if it is empty than it will come
hence all will come.
so you have to use if else.
please do a google for the proper if else syntax. but logic will be these only.

thanks

Comment: But you need to explain *why*

Answer (score 0):

The OR operator checks if any of the expressions are true, then it would return true.

In your case 
    ''='' 
is always true so the SELECT query returns all the records.